# more efficient way to cut through 3D matrix along all the plains in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to cut a 3D array along all it's plains. To capture 2D arrays along all the axes of the 3D array, this will create 13 2D arrays. I was wondering if there is a way to do this with axis and rotations? This will create 3 vertical and 3 horizontal slices front to back and 3 vertical left to right and 4 diagonal.

```
     import numpy as np
     r = np.array([
     [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [2,8,9]],
      
     [[10,11,12],
     [13,14,15],
     [2,17,18]],                                                                      
       
     [[19,20,21],
     [22,23,24],
     [25,26,27]],
     ])  
     
     a = np.vstack([r[0,:,0],r[1,:,0],r[2,:,0]]) 
     b = np.vstack([r[0,:,1],r[1,:,1],r[2,:,1]]) 
     c = np.vstack([r[0,:,2],r[1,:,2],r[2,:,2]]) 
    
     d = np.vstack([r[0,0,:],r[1,0,:],r[2,0,:]]) 
     e = np.vstack([r[0,1,:],r[1,1,:],r[2,1,:]]) 
     f = np.vstack([r[0,2,:],r[1,2,:],r[2,2,:]]) 
    
     g = r[0]
     h = r[1]
     i = r[2]
     
     j = np.vstack([r[0,:,0],r[1,:,1],r[2,:,2]]) 
     k = np.vstack([r[0,:,2],r[1,:,1],r[2,:,0]]) 
     l = np.vstack([r[0,2,:],r[1,1,:],r[2,0,:]]) 
     m = np.vstack([r[0,0,:],r[1,1,:],r[2,2,:]]) 
     al= np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m])  
    
     print(al,end='\n')
     # output
     [[[ 1  4  2]  #a
     [10 13  2]
     [19 22 25]]
    
     [[ 2  5  8]   #b
     [11 14 17]
     [20 23 26]]
    
     [[ 3  6  9]   #c
     [12 15 18]
     [21 24 27]]
    
     [[ 1  2  3]   #d
     [10 11 12]
     [19 20 21]]
    
     [[ 4  5  6]   #e
     [13 14 15]
     [22 23 24]]
    
     [[ 2  8  9]   #f
     [ 2 17 18]
     [25 26 27]]
    
     [[ 1  2  3]   #g
     [ 4  5  6]
     [ 2  8  9]]
    
     [[10 11 12]   #h
     [13 14 15]      
     [ 2 17 18]]     
                     
     [[19 20 21]   #i
     [22 23 24]      
     [25 26 27]]     
                     
     [[ 1  4  2]   #j
     [11 14 17]
     [21 24 27]]
    
     [[ 3  6  9]   #k
     [11 14 17]
     [19 22 25]]
    
     [[ 2  8  9]   #l
     [13 14 15]
     [19 20 21]]
    
     [[ 1  2  3]   #m
     [13 14 15]
     [25 26 27]]]
```

Comment: *j...m* are not slices along a plain. What's the logic for those? For example *j* is a diagonal slice but transposed.

Comment: Assuming that the indices of the remaining axes should be preserved, many slices are flipped or transposed.

Comment: for my own knowledge I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of getting the same output.